# Having problem showing IMG in website after exporting it from database/Sqlite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sqlite, jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Product = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [image, Setimage] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/data')
    .then(response  => (response.json()))
    .then(result => setData(result.data))
    .catch(error => (error));
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!data || !data.length) return;

    Promise.all(data.map(d =>
      tobase64(d.Image)
      .then(base64 => ({id: d.id, base64}))
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
      ))
      .then(images => Setimage(images))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }, [data]);

  const tobase64 = file => {
    const blobIM = new Blob([file.buffer], {type: "image/jpeg"});
    const reader = new FileReader();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reader.readAsDataURL(blobIM);
    reader.onload = () => {
      const imageType = blobIM.type;
      if (imageType === "image/jpeg" || imageType === "image/png") {
        resolve(reader.result.split(',')[1]);
      } else {
        reject(new Error("Invalid image type. ONly PNG and JPG are supported."))
      }
    };
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });
};

  return (
    <div className='w-full flex justify-between flex-col'>
      <h1 className='text-white text-[40px]'>Data from back end test</h1>
      <ul>
        {data.map(data => (
          <li className='text-secondary' key={data.id}>{data.Description}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <div>
        {image &&
          image.map(img => (
            <div className='w-full flex' key={img.id}>
              <div>
                <img
                  className='flex h-64 w-64'
                  src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${img.base64}`}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Product
```

The image is being retrieved from a SQLite database, which uses `BLOB` to store the buffer of a JPEG. Even thought the placeholder for the image is displayed, the image itself is black. Why is that?

This is the the data that is being fetched:

```
Image: ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 0d 09 0a 0b 0a 08 0d 0b 0a 0b 0e 0e 0d 0f 13 20 15 13 12 12 13 27 1c 1e 17 ... 223858 more bytes
```

First I try to use the (reader) to turn the buffer into base64: Give me a error

Later realize that I also have to change the file into a (Blob): Fix the blob problem, but now it gave me a error saying the result is a string

Use (useEffect) for data to fix the string problem: Now the place holder appears but the img itself is black

Comment: ...why are you using Base64?

Comment: Was having problems using other data types for Sqlite

Comment: What's the exact value of `img.base64`? Try rendering only the `<img>` just in case you're leaking some weird style or something.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.